# Show the following matrices are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be similar matrices.

$1)$Show that $A^n,B^n$ are similar.

$2)$Show that for every polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{K[x]}$, $f(A),f(B)$ are similar.

With induction i showed that $A^n,B^n$ are similar, but i don't know what to do for the second part.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $B$ are similar means there exists a invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$. Then note that $B^2=(P^{-1}AP)^2=P^{-1}APP^{-1}AP=P^{-1}A^2P.$

So $A^2$ and $ B^2$ are similar.

Also note that all polynomials are but linear combinations of the powers of these matrices. Now $aB^k+bB^j=aP^{-1}A^kP+bP^{-1}A^jP=P^{-1}(aA^k+bA^j)P$

Comment: As I stated, I showed the first part. My problem is with the polynomials.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you understand it now?

Answer (score 0):

$A,B$ are similar **iff** there is an invertible $Q$ such that
$AQ = QB$.

We see that $A^n Q = A^{n-1}AQ = A^{n-1} QB = ... = Q B^n$ and
hence
for any polynomial $p(x) = \sum_k a_k x^k$ we have
$p(A) Q = \sum_k a_k A^k Q = \sum_k a_k Q B^k = Q p(B)$. Hence
$p(A)$ and $p(B)$ are similar.